Batch labeling GPT partitions
I know one can use the parted or gdisk tool to label partitions in a GPT one by one interactively. However,
Is it possible to give labels to the gpt partitions via command line in batch mode please?

Parted has an option to script commands (-s) however it doesn't allow to script what it deems as "destructive" actions. The definition of "destructive" is kinda up to the developers, so it may not work.
